# What is the difference between $f/g \to 1$ versus $m < f/g < M$ eventually?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

For simplicity, suppose $f, g$ are positive functions defined on the positive real numbers. (1) Let “$f/g \to 1$” mean that $f(x)/g(x)$ approaches $1$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$. (2) Let “$m < f/g < M$ eventually” mean that there exist $m, M > 0$ such that, for some $N > 0$, $m < f(x)/g(x) < M$ for all $x \geq N$.

I think (1) implies (2) because we can just choose any $0 < m < 1$ and $M > 1$. However, (2) doesn’t imply (1) because e.g. we can just let $f, g$ be two distinct constant functions; then (2) is true but (1) is false.

What I'm wondering is why there are these two notions. When might we use one over the other? They both seem to capture some idea of $f, g$ being of the “same order of magnitude” or "same asymptotic growth rate", although (1) is strictly stronger. Are there any common/important examples where we only have one condition satisfied but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some functions that don't "settle down" and converge to anything, but we can still give it reasonable bounds. For example, we cannot say that $\sin(x)\to a$ for any $a\in\mathbb R$ as $x\to\infty$, but it is true that $-1\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$ eventually (and actually, for all $x$).  If you want to only look at positive numbers, then just add  a constant to $\sin(x)$. If you want to make the second notion only true "eventually" (and not for all $x$), you can look at something like $\sin(x)(1+e^{-x})$.

Comment: For your example of $\sin(x)(1 + e^{-x})$, the bound $M$ would technically have to be greater than 1, yes?

Comment: @twosigma That's right, since $e^{-x}>0$.

Answer (score 2):

The first condition means that $f$ and $g$ behave very similarly when $x$ grows and tend to coincide. The second condition expresses the fact that the ratio of $f$ and $g$ is a function bounded from above and below, so its graph will lie in a strip for $x$ large enough. You clearly see the latter behavior with $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x)=1$. On the other hand $\sin x$ does not have a limit when $x \to \infty$.